# How to rename merge commit message?

Tags: git, rebase

I did `git merge master` twice, apparently this company prefer rebase instead of merge.

[image: merge commits]

those 2 merge commit (deedb27e, 65b4d3fcc) need to be renamed or it would rejected by the upstream (the have checks that would reject any commit without proper format).

I've tried right clicking those two merge commits on IntelliJ, it have "Edit commit message" disabled.

[image]

Also tried `git rebase -p` but it shows `fatal: --preserve-merges was replaced by --rebase-merges`, so I tried that, it shows a progress, but the history still the same

```
git rebase --rebase-merges                                                                                                                                                                                            Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/rm-v1.
```

How can I rewrite the local history so it doesn't have those `"Merge branch 'master' into rm-v1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to rename merge commit message?

You can still do a rebase interactive and rename your commits
[image]

But I suggest to create a clean new branch from master, cherry pick your relevant commits in the branch `rm-v1` and resolving conflicts if needed. then you can have a beautiful MR without merge commit.

Comment: yup that's what i did, reset the HEAD back to original PR then `git rebase master`, weirdly didn't work for the first and 2nd time but works for the third time..